# Making modal window disappear on end of hover...without jitter

Tags: jquery, hover, modal-dialog

I want to have a Javascript modal popup windows appear when I mouse over a list entry, and disappear when the mouse leaves the link (or the modal popup) -- so the user won't have to click an X to make the window go away.  The purpose of the window is to give more information about the link without requiring the user to click or go to a new page.

I am using jQuery's hover:

```
// Function called to open the window:
function openModalPopupWindow() 
{
  document.getElementById('modalMask').style.display = 'inline-block';  // Make the modal popup stuff visible
} 

// Function called to close the window:
function closeModalPopupWindow() 
{
  document.getElementById('modalMask').style.display = 'none';      // Make the modal popup stuff invisible:
} 

$("li").hover(
  function (e) {
    $(this).append($("<span> ***</span>"));
    openModalPopupWindow ();
  }, 
  function (e) {
    $(this).find("span:last").remove();
    closeModalPopupWindow ();
  }
);
```

in this HTML file:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.2.js'></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="modal.css" id="css">
</head>
<body>
 <ul>
     <li>Coke</li>
     <li>Pepsi</li>
     <li>R. C.</li>
 </ul>

 <div id="modalMask">
  <div id="modalContent">
   <p>This is a "modal" popup window.</p>
  </div>
 </div>
 <script src="modal.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that the modal popup jitters in and out of existence as I move the mouse over the item.  I'd guess that there's something like focus here:  the popup took precedence when it became visible, so when I move the mouse, the mouse pointer is no longer hovering over the list element, and the modal popup goes away.  But then the mouse pointer is over the element again, so it comes back, etc.

What's a good way to make this jitter go away?

TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Total Answer Edit**

What is happening here is that your mask is covering the intended hover position. 
A SIMPLE fix would be to give the `ul`a higher z-index than your mask.

simply add this to your css: http://jsfiddle.net/e8f7P/3/

```
ul{
    position:relative;
    z-index:1001;  
}
```

If that is not the effect you are looking for, but you still want the functionality, you will have to make a pseudo hover spot.  Basically you have to recreate your list spots, but make them basically invisible (no content) and give them a higher z-index.

Let me know which direction you would like to go, if the latter of the two options is your desired effect, I can help you out.

Comment: Aaah, This is a different problem.  I'm sorry, I didn't understand your question.  Doing what you are looking for requires you to play with z-index and empty divs.  I will answer again

Comment: No problem, just leave a comment and I'll respond when I can.  Also - make sure you clear your cache or make a console.log("TEST") in your javascript and check to log to make sure the current code is running

Comment: Yes, you can either move it so the modal mask doesn't cover the links, or you can create a container div for your ul and li's and create a duplicate list with no content, that duplicate list will overlay the old list and also be on top of the modal mask.

Comment: Great! I'm glad you found a good solution for your needs!  Congrats!